# Reset StackNavigator on Button Press React Native

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I'm currently in the process of teaching myself to make an app with React Native. I'm using React Navigation to navigate between screens on button presses. I can navigate screens just fine. However, on one navigation I also want to reset the **`stackNavigator`**. I have looked at solutions for resetting the `stackNavigator` using `NavigationActions.reset()` method, but I cannot get it to work for a Button. Just to rehash, I am stuck trying use a button to both navigate to a new screen and reset the `stackNavigator`. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationActions, StackActions, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json



class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
     render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Home Screen</Text>
                <Button
                  title="Join Group"
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push('JoinGroup')}
                />
                <Button
                  title="Create Group"
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push('CreateGroup')}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class JoinGroupScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Join Here</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class Index extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Index</Text>
                <Button
                    title="Login"
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push('Login')}
                />
                <Button
                    title="Register"
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push('Register')}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

/* This Screen contains the button where I want to navigate screens and reset the StackNavigator */

class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Login Here</Text>
                <Button
                    title="Login"
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
                />
            </View>
         );
    }
}

class CreateGroupScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Create Here</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    JoinGroup: {
        screen: JoinGroupScreen,
    },
    CreateGroup: {
        screen: CreateGroupScreen,
    },
    Login: {
        screen: LoginScreen,
    },
    Index: {
        screen: Index,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Index',
  }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <RootStack />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code to reset stack navigator in react navigation version 1:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [ NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' }) ]
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

In react navigation version 2 it has changed and you can use this code:

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

In your case, you can use it like this:

```
/* This Screen contains the button where I want to navigate screens and reset the StackNavigator */

class LoginScreen extends React.Component {

render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Login Here</Text>
                <Button
                    title="Login"
                    onPress={() => { 
                       const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
                           index: 0,
                           actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' })],
                       });
                       this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
                    }
                />
           </View>
       );
   }
}
```

Comment: So how should I set the onPress field for the button in order to use this code(forgive me, I am very new to this)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answer was not quite correct, but what you gave me was enough to help me figure it out. If you edit the import statement to also include StackActions and change the NavigationActions.reset to StackActions.reset I will check mark this post. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @JadenZerbe you are right! My code is for react navigation V1 and it has changed in version 2!  i edited my answer, thanks for your comment :)

Comment: @AliSn Thanks so much. If only I had stumbled upon your answer earlier, I would have saved 3 hours from my life. Kudos!!!

Comment: @PranjalGore Happy to hear that :-)

Answer (score 0):

> **Now this will work with React Navigation 2.0**

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

     const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
          index: 0,
        key: null,
          actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' })],
        });
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from 'react-navigation';

if (response.success){
  const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
                  index: 0,
                  actions:[NavigationActions.navigate({routeName:'Home'})],
              });
  this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
}
```